# after i add new data in core data collection it can't be saved (multiply validation error occured)

Tags: core-data

The code bellow add to Core data issues, but after it added, I can't save with error   (multiply validation error occured)

```
MySQLIXC *ixcDatabase = [[MySQLIXC alloc] init];
NSArray *destinationsForSaleList = [ixcDatabase destinationsForSaleList:carrier];
NSFetchRequest *request1 = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request1 setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DestinationsList"   
inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
for (NSDictionary *destinationsForSale in destinationsForSaleList) {

    NSManagedObject *object1 = [NSEntityDescription 
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DestinationsList" 
                               inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    NSLog(@"Moc: %@",managedObjectContext);

    [object1 setValue:@"y" forKey:@"weAreSoldIt"];
    // changeDate        
    NSString *chdate = [destinationsForSale objectForKey:@"chdate"];
    NSDateFormatter *changeDate = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [object1 setValue:[changeDate dateFromString:chdate] forKey:@"changeDate"];
    NSLog(@"Carrier :%@  Destination name:%@",carrier, destinationsForSale);

    //Country
    [object1 setValue:[destinationsForSale objectForKey:@"country"] forKey:@"country"];

    //rate
    NSNumberFormatter *rate = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init ]autorelease];
    [object1 setValue:[rate numberFromString:[destinationsForSale objectForKey:@"price"]] forKey:@"rate"];
```

Unfortunately I can't fix a bug by the way which u propose bellow.
Bcs Entity DestinationList must have relations with Entity Carriers by project understanding.
That is how I try to fix it:

```
[objectDestinationList setValue:objectCarrier forKey:@"carrier"];
```

I was send to method my carrier object as object, but it doesn't work.

In this case, I don't know how is a way to fix it around. Bcs I see error, but don't see case why error is start.

Do u know a simple code to correct add relationships to Entity? All what I catch around internet is a core data book ,my Marcus Zarra and his very hard to understanding example. His showing a complex solution, I can understand it, but using programming style which not very easy for me at this moment (according my one month experience in cocoa programming ;)

Here is additional information: How I create Carrier instance. I have managedObjectContext, which I receive to class from AppDelegate.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Carrier"
                              inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
NSManagedObject *carrier = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]
```

by the same way I prepare NSManagedObject for DestinationsList Entity.

After that I add all values to NSManagedObject for destinationsList, I have to make relationship between Carrer NSManagedObject and destinationsList. In this case I have trouble. Bellow is how I try to update relationship for Carrier entity:

```
    NSSet *newDestSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:objectDestination,nil];
    [objectCarrier setValue:newDestSet forKey:@"destinationsList"];
```

finally I have 2010-11-03 21:22:56.968 snow[20301:a0f] -[NSCFArray initialize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c44e40

Bellow is my class interface deescription:

```
  @interface InitUpdateIXC : NSObject {

NSInteger destinationType;
}

-(void) updateCarrierList:(NSManagedObjectContext       *)managedObjectContext;
-(void)updateDestinationList:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext 
              forCarrier:(NSString *)carrierName 
        forCarrierObject:(NSManagedObject *)objectCarrier 
         destinationType:(NSInteger)destinationType;
@end
```

Yep, bellow in answer present correct model, but some different is here. 
At first, i don't have separate class for Entity as u present in you model. My current class is just NSManagedObject
In second, relationship "carrier" is non-optional for Entity DestinationsList.

**SOLUTION AND ERROR DESCRIPTION:**

In case of trouble, what happened with my code:
When i try to add setValue forKey with back relationship from DestinationsList to Carrier, i forget that NSManagmentObject return every time array, not just object.
This is a reason why i receive error about array init problem.

Solution is not sent Carrier object to method, bcs for me was too hard to extract from array correct object without key value. I was using a predicate access to extract object to array and lastObject function to extract correct object from array. After that i set accroding value and everything working fine.
A solution not look like cocoa-style, so better way is refactor it in future, any suggestion wellcome.
Here is appropriate code:

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Carrier"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name =%@",carrierName];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil; 
    NSArray *currentCarriers = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    [objectDestination setValue:[currentCarriers lastObject] forKey:@"carrier"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something like this for you 'save'

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
        { 
        // Handle the error. 
        NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
        if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0)
            {
            for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors)
                {
                NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
                }
            }
        else
            {
            NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);
            }
        }
```

At least, then you can see what the multiple errors are. If you post those, someone may be able to offer more help.

One thought, though, is that there is something buggy about your data model - like non-optional attribute with no value, etc.

If you create NSManagedObject subclassed Carrier and DestinationsList, then in Carrier.h you should have some method declarations like this. (Assuming that Carrier to-many DestinationsList is called 'destinationsLists'.)

```
@interface Carrier (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addDestinationsListsObject:(Run *)destinationsList;
- (void)removeDestinationsListsObject:(Run *)destinationsList;
- (void)addDestinationsLists:(NSSet *)destinationsLists;
- (void)removeDestinationsLists:(NSSet *)destinationsLists;
@end
```

Once these are declared, you should be able to add a DestinationsList to a Carrier with a line like this:

```
[myCarrier addDestinationsListsObject:myDestinationsList];
```

Not seeing your full data model, it is difficult to know what is happening and what would help fix it.

Do you have something like this for your model definition?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank u very much. NSLocalizedDescription = "carrier is a required value.". Looks like when i add Entity which have inverse relationship, i have to add it also. This is non-optional for me to protect me for unused data in core data store.

Comment: If i have relationship named carrier, how i can connect it from code, if i have name attribute in entity carrier?

Comment: When i was add object carrier to relationships, i seen final error in saving: 2 -[NSAlert alertWithError:] called with nil NSError. A generic error message will be displayed, but the user deserves better. The operation could not be completed.No other information is available about the problem. But in this time, i don't seen any troubles, core data save as well database.

Comment: Try setting 'carrier' relationship (or attribute) to 'Optional' in your .xcdatamodel. This should address "carrier is a required value" error. If that does 'fix' the bug, then you will need to go back and modify your code to set 'carrier' for all objects *before* saving. And, of course, you should also reinstate carrier as non-optional (required) at that point, too.

Comment: I don't know enough about your data model to answer your second question. I don't know what entity has 'carrier' as a relationship. If DestinationsList has property 'carrier', then you should have something like: [theDestinationsList setCarrier:theCarrier]. If relationship has defined inverse relationship, then you do not have to explicitly set the inverse. In other words, you do *not* have to do this: [theCarrier addDestinationsListObject:theDestinationsList].

Comment: Carrier have toomany relationship named destinationsList to DestinationList entity with inverse non optional relationship to Carrier entity.

Comment: So, every DestinationList *must* have a Carrier. But a Carrier may have zero, one or many DestinationLists? And now things are working?

Comment: Yep, but i don't know correct way to setup relationship from DestinationList to a Carrier from code. This is issue which i asked in main question.

Comment: Have you subclassed NSManagedObject to create Carrier and DestinationsList? Also, I realize that I do not understand your data model. Is it that a Carrier has many Destinations or is it that a Carrier has many Destination Lists?

Comment: i was update main question with code. Carrier have many DestinationsList, there no Destinations

Comment: I modified my answer (above) so that I could format code snippets

Comment: I can't post images. But i don't see a way how i can decide my trouble. Bsc i still don't have solution how i can setup too-many non-optional relationship between two entities.